# Is there any simple way to run coroutines in js without using a third-party library?

Tags: javascript, coroutine, frame-rate, babylonjs

Trying to do something similar to Babylon.js's https://doc.babylonjs.com/divingDeeper/events/coroutines

```
    const spawnMeshesCoroutine = function* () {
      spawnTheFirstMesh();
      yield;
      spawnTheSecondMesh();
      yield;
      spawnTheThirdMesh();
    };
    scene.onBeforeRenderObservable.runCoroutineAsync(spawnMeshesCoroutine());
```

But wondering if there are any simple JS examples to run a simpler coroutine that may handle some expensive tasks in JS without blocking the UI.

An experiment with "expensive tasks": [Looking for solutions to enable non-blocking 60fps autosuggest UI for react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72073597/looking-for-solutions-to-enable-non-blocking-60fps-autosuggest-ui-for-react)

Comment: JS is single-threaded, so you can either run code using `async` and `await` (or Promises. Same thing, different syntax) or if you want true "code that runs off-the-main-thread" you want [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: Well of course you can write a first-party library, but no, you will need a runner and some way to define the "expensive tasks".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -3):

A way to run a function across multiple event loops is:

```js
async function spawnFirstMeshAsync() {
  return spawnFirstMesh();
}

async function spawnSecondMeshAsync() {
  return spawnSecondMesh();
}

async function spawnThirdMeshAsync() {
  return spawnThirdMesh();
}

async function spawnMeshes() {
  await spawnFirstMesh();
  await spawnSecondMesh();
  await spawnThirdMesh();
}
```

In terms of synchronizing with frames as Babylon.js does, look into `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: This code executes the three meshes sequentially; it would be better to

`await Promise.all([spawnFirstMesh(), spawnSecondMesh(), spawnThirdMesh()]);`